# Why would a packet travel from the client back to the client itself?

Tags: networking

The definition of RTT, Round-Trip Time, given in my book is as follows:

"the time it takes for a small packet to travel from client to server
and then back to the client."

Why would a packet travel from the client back to the client itself?

Comment: Most network protocols are bidirectional, using a request and response.

Comment: so, in this definition, the packet that travels from the client is not the same packet that travels back to the client

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acknowledgement_(data_networks)

Answer (score 1):

The explanation in your book is vague. It doesn't quite convey the meaning. 
Round Trip Time, or RTT, is the summation of:
1) Time taken by a `request` packet (sent by the client) to reach the server, and
2) Time taken by an `acknowledgement` packet (sent by the server) to reach the client.

Hence, in layman terms, what your book says is correct that `it's the time taken by a small packet to travel from client to server and then back to itself`, but in actual terms, there are 2 different packets being exchanged. One as a request to the server, and the other as an acknowledgement of reception of client's request by the server